# How to prevent Click and DoubleClick events collisions in GXT Grid?

Tags: java, click, gxt, double-click

I am using GXT2.2.5's `Grid` and want to handle both `Click` and the `DoubleClick` events.

The problem is that when doing so, the `Click` event is sometimes called twice for each `DoubleClick` fired. My aim is to prevent that second call to `Click`.

Here is the relevant code:

```java
grid.addListener(Events.OnDoubleClick, new Listener<BaseEvent>() {
    public void handleEvent(BaseEvent e) {
        GridEvent event = (GridEvent) e;
        doubleClick(getSelectedContent());
    }
});

view.getGridContent().addListener(Events.OnClick, new Listener<BaseEvent>() {
    public void handleEvent(BaseEvent be) {
        final GridEvent event = (GridEvent) be;

        Date date = new Date(); 
        long current =  date.getTime();

        if ((current - lastClicked) > 1000){
            click(getSelectedContent());
        }
        lastClicked = current;                              
    }
});
```

As can be seen, my current approach is to check that the second click is triggered after 1000 milliseconds, than delegate the call to `click()`, but that doesn't function properly.

How to solve this otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

Use the getClickCount() method. This method tell about the kind of click (ie. Single, Double, Triple, and further....etc), but does NOT keep tracks of the number of clicks made...

Using this method u can know that whether the click was single or double,triple,etc...then on the basis of that u can take your decision.

Comment: how can i get getClickCount() method from GridEvent?